# Activity Permission - Prevent User to View Other User Activity - CiviCRM

Tags: activities, evaluating-civicrm, activity

I'm asking about activity permission in CiviCRM. I've tried to search by default functionality to prevent user to view other user activity but i guess there is no feature to do this.

This is the case that I want. Example : There are 5 users in CiviCRM : Barnie, JohnDoe, Michelle, Danielle & Felix. User JohnDoe create new activity type "Phone Call" with contact user Danielle and assign to user Barnie.

[image: See image]

What I want is : While user Felix login into system, while he find activities, that phone call activities above will not showed to him.

[image]

Can you show me where is the code to execute query to prevent current user to view activity(s) that's not related to him/her?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will require a custom extension to extend the ACLs such that the only folk who can see an Activity are those who are an Activity Contact (or who have View all Activities permission).

AFAIK this sort of permissioning is currently only provided through CiviCase but you have already indicated you want this as a new feature for Activities.

Search existing [Extensions](https://civicrm.org/extensions/) in case someone already developed this.

If you want assistance to build such an extension I suggest you try one (but only one) of the following so no one growls about cross-posting

- https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/dev
- https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/dev-newcomers
- https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/extensions

or if you want professional support you can find Partners such as Fuzion listed [here](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors).

Another approach, if you were using Drupal, and were interested in keeping most folk outside civicrm and have them interact mostly through Views and Webforms would be to build a View which would limit the Activities displayed to the Current User to those where they are a 'contact' on the Activity.

We do this quite a lot for clients who have lots of users but few who really need to get deep inside civicrm and bounce folk between using Views to find info and then Webforms to add/update.

Hope that helps.